# Getting JSON array data from Twig

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, twig

I need to pass an array passed in Twig as a parameter for a javascript object.

```
        $app->render("site/home.twig.html", array(
        "page" => "home",
        "trans" => $translationfile
    ));
```

$translationfile is a value generated from json_decode'ing a JSON file containing translation values.

When I attempt to access the part of the file I want to access;

```
var translations = "{{ trans.production }}";
```

I get "Array" as an answer.

I assume there's a way to obtain the array? Do I need to encode it?

Comment: from the [documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/json_encode.html) ...

Comment: I've tried this earlier, but as soon as I try to parse the JSON in JS, I run into this error: "Unexpected token & in JSON".

Comment: What is the content of your array?

Comment: {&quot;header_title&quot;:&quot;Title&quot;,&quot;header_meta&quot;:&quot;Meta&quot;,&quot;projet1&quot;:{&quot;header&quot;:&quot;Title&quot;,&quot;text&quot;:&quot;Description&quot;},&quot;projet2&quot;:{&quot;header&quot;:&quot;Title&quot;,&quot;text&quot;:&quot;Description&quot;}}

From the JS. I'd assume this is already parsed? If so, how do I access it?

Comment: Twig is escaping the output, the correct answer would be `var translations = {{ trans.production | json_encode() | raw }};`

Comment: That fixes my issue, but while you're here, I think I should ask another question. In this situation, I have a script that's loaded from an internal src, so <script src="/assets/js/components/internaljs.js"></script>. The only solution I've found to pass the data from {{ trans }} is to pass it through an object variable. Am I doing this wrong?

Comment: You mean if you want to pass twig data to an external javascript file you place it in a JS variable before loading the script? In that case, yes that the only way